# cpp publisher/subscriber tutorial loosing some messages

Tags: c++, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was following the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B)) and faced the following problem: some messages (usually 3) are lost when doing the sequence:

1. start talker
2. start listener
3. stop talker
4. start talker

For example, an output like this is produced in the talker window:

```
$ rosrun beginner_tutorials talker 
[ INFO] [1548238652.003693516]: hello world 0
[ INFO] [1548238652.103993652]: hello world 1
[ INFO] [1548238652.203964623]: hello world 2
[ INFO] [1548238652.304064752]: hello world 3
[ INFO] [1548238652.404034941]: hello world 4
...
```

While in the listener window only latter are shown:

```
[ INFO] [1548238652.304599291]: I heard: [hello world 3]
[ INFO] [1548238652.404490112]: I heard: [hello world 4]
[ INFO] [1548238652.504314152]: I heard: [hello world 5]
...
```

There is no such problem with the Python publisher/subscriber, not even a single message was lost.

ROS Kinetic, Ubuntu 16.04.05 x64 (run under VirtualBox with Win7 x64 as a host). No original files were changed, just copy and paste from the tutorials.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313491/cpp-publisher/subscriber-tutorial-loosing-some-messages/) by [volume_8091](https://answers.ros.org/users/39641/volume_8091/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2019-01-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [curi_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/37504/curi_ros/) on 2019-01-23**:
You could try increasing the queue size of the publisher. However, there is no guarantee that all messages will be delivered.

**Comment by [mali](https://answers.ros.org/users/36867/mali/) on 2019-01-23**:
if you lose only the first three messages each time you start the talker node, the reason might be that: the publisher takes milliseconds to be initialized. try to put some delay like 1 sec before publishing any message and see what will happen.

**Comment by [volume_8091](https://answers.ros.org/users/39641/volume_8091/) on 2019-01-24**:
@curi_ROS increasing queue size from 1000 to 10,000 did not give any difference. As only 3 messages were lost, buffer size of 1000 would already be enough to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

As you already noticed, this is caused by the time it takes to initialize the Publisher. I wanted to share an alternate solution to the problem, which is using the **getNumSubscribers()** method of the [Publisher](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1Publisher.html) class.

This method returns the number of subscribers that are currently connected to the Publisher. In your case, you could add something like this to the talker.cpp code:

```
while(chatter_pub.getNumSubscribers() == 0)
    loop_rate.sleep();
```

This would go right before the publish of the message:

```
chatter_pub.publish(msg);
```

This way, you won't publish any message until the Publisher/Subscriber connection is created, so you won't lose any message. You can also check the following [post](http://www.theconstructsim.com/ros-qa-176-publisher-subscriber-tutorial-loosing-some-messages-cpp/) for more details.

Cheers,

---

Originally posted by [Alberto E.](https://answers.ros.org/users/31003/alberto-e./) with karma: 356 on 2019-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-24**:
+1 for mentioning `getNumSubscribers()`, but a nitpick: you write "**the** Publisher/Subscriber", as if there are only 1 of each. That is rarely the case. There are typically many, in which case waiting for a single one makes little sense.

Same comment about the text in the blogpost you link to.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-24**:
It would be good to link to / discuss an explanation of when to use which type of interaction, as "lost messages" are almost inherent to something as loosely / completely decoupled as (ROS) pub-sub.

If lost msgs are unacceptable, perhaps services or actions are better suited.

**Comment by [volume_8091](https://answers.ros.org/users/39641/volume_8091/) on 2019-01-24**:
Not only did your solution work, but it is also much more reliable and avoids ugly guess-waiting-time question.

**Comment by [volume_8091](https://answers.ros.org/users/39641/volume_8091/) on 2019-01-24**:
@Alberto E. As a final note, could you share a piece of advice on how to look up the *names* of subscribers? This could enable not starting publishing until the very important Subscriber(s) starts listening.

UPD: the video is good, thank you very much

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-24**:\

> This could enable not starting publishing until the very important Subscriber(s) starts listening.

and would also remove one of the advantages of pub-sub: decoupling in the space dimension.

See #q203129.